# How to rotate the Canvas on fix angle or item

Tags: java, android, android-canvas

This is my code to rotate the wheel and sound cordinator according to rotation but I want to rotate the wheel according to fix color on fix point.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Paint.Style;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import com.spin.wheel.manager.MyDBAdapter;
import com.spin.wheel.manager.Prefs;
import com.spin.wheel.ui.activity.HomeActivity;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

 public class WheelView extends View {
public boolean lifted;
private Paint circlePaint;
private long currTime;
private String item;
private Paint item10Paint;
private Paint item11Paint;
private Paint item12Paint;
private Paint item13Paint;
private Paint item14Paint;
private Paint item15Paint;
private Paint item1Paint;
private Paint item2Paint;
private Paint item3Paint;
private Paint item4Paint;
private Paint item5Paint;
private Paint item6Paint;
private Paint item7Paint;
private Paint item8Paint;
private Paint item9Paint;
private float itemLength;
private List<String> itemNames;
private double lastTheta;
private String listName;
private Paint markerPaint;
private long oldTime;
private Paint pointerPaint;
private int px;
WheelView wheelView;
private int py;
private float radius;
private MediaPlayer resourcePlayer;
private Paint rimPaint;
    private double rotationOffset;
private int selected;
private Paint textPaint;
private boolean textSet;
private long timeDiff;
private Paint titlePaint;
private String winner;
int padding;
int center;
Context mContext;

public WheelView(Context context) {

    super(context);
    mContext=context;
    initWheelView();
}

public WheelView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    mContext=context;
    initWheelView();
}

public WheelView(Context context, AttributeSet ats, int defaultStyle) {
    super(context, ats, defaultStyle);
    mContext=context;
    initWheelView();
}

protected void initWheelView() {
    setFocusable(true);
    Resources r = getResources();
    this.circlePaint = new Paint(1);
    this.circlePaint.setColor(r.getColor(R.color.wheel_color));
    this.circlePaint.setStrokeWidth(5.0f);
    this.circlePaint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
    this.rimPaint = new Paint(1);
    this.rimPaint.setColor(r.getColor(R.color.text_color));
    this.rimPaint.setStrokeWidth(1.0f);
    this.rimPaint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
    this.textPaint = new Paint(1);
    this.textPaint.setColor(r.getColor(R.color.text_color));
    this.titlePaint = new Paint(1);
    this.titlePaint.setColor(r.getColor(R.color.text_color));
    this.pointerPaint = new Paint(1);
    this.pointerPaint.setColor(r.getColor(R.color.pointer_color));
    this.markerPaint = new Paint(1);
    this.markerPaint.setStrokeWidth(2.0f);
    this.markerPaint.setColor(r.getColor(R.color.marker_color));
    this.item1Paint = new Paint(1);
    this.item1Paint.setColor(r.getColor(R.color.item1_color));
    this.item2Paint = new Paint(1);
    this.item2Paint.setColor(r.getColor(R.color.item2_color));
    this.item3Paint = new Paint(1);
    this.item3Paint.setColor(r.getColor(R.color.item3_color));
    this.item4Paint = new Paint(1);
    this.item4Paint.setColor(r.getColor(R.color.item4_color));
    this.item5Paint = new Paint(1);
    this.item5Paint.setColor(r.getColor(R.color.item5_color));
    this.item6Paint = new Paint(1);
    this.item6Paint.setColor(r.getColor(R.color.item6_color));
    this.item7Paint = new Paint(1);
    this.item7Paint.setColor(r.getColor(R.color.item7_color));
    this.item8Paint = new Paint(1);
    this.item8Paint.setColor(r.getColor(R.color.item8_color));
    this.item9Paint = new Paint(1);
    this.item9Paint.setColor(r.getColor(R.color.item9_color));
    this.item10Paint = new Paint(1);
    this.item10Paint.setColor(r.getColor(R.color.item10_color));
    this.item11Paint = new Paint(1);
    this.item11Paint.setColor(r.getColor(R.color.item11_color));
    this.item12Paint = new Paint(1);
    this.item12Paint.setColor(r.getColor(R.color.item12_color));
    this.item13Paint = new Paint(1);
    this.item13Paint.setColor(r.getColor(R.color.item13_color));
    this.item14Paint = new Paint(1);
    this.item14Paint.setColor(r.getColor(R.color.item14_color));
    this.item15Paint = new Paint(1);
    this.item15Paint.setColor(r.getColor(R.color.item15_color));
    this.lifted = false;
    this.selected = -1;
    this.lastTheta = 0.0d;
    this.timeDiff = 0;
    this.oldTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    this.currTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    this.winner = "";
    this.resourcePlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getContext(), R.raw.wheel_sound_new);
    this.item = "";
    this.itemLength = 0.0f;
    this.listName = "";
    this.textSet = false;
}


  protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
   setMeasuredDimension(measure(widthMeasureSpec), measure(heightMeasureSpec));

   int width = Math.min(getMeasuredWidth(), getMeasuredHeight());

   padding = getPaddingLeft() == 0 ? 0 : getPaddingLeft();
   radius = width - padding * 2;
   center = width / 2;




   }

private int measure(int measureSpec) {
    int specMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(measureSpec);
    int specSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(measureSpec);
    if (specMode == 0) {
        return 200;
    }
    return specSize;
}

public boolean withinWheel(float _x, float _y) {
    return getRadius() * getRadius() > ((_x - ((float) getPX())) * (_x - ((float) getPX()))) + ((((float) getPY()) - _y) * (((float) getPY()) - _y));
}

public void setList(String _listName) {
    this.listName = _listName;
}

public void setRotation(double _rotation) {
    Log.e("@@_rotation", String.valueOf(_rotation));
    this.rotationOffset = _rotation % 360.0d;
}

public double getRotationNumber() {

    Log.e("@@rotationOffset", String.valueOf(rotationOffset));
    return this.rotationOffset;
}

public void setLastTheta(double _lastTheta, float width) {
    float offset = 12800.0f / width;
    if (_lastTheta < -40.0d) {
        _lastTheta = (double) (-offset);
    }
    if (_lastTheta > 40.0d) {
        _lastTheta = (double) offset;
    }
    this.lastTheta = _lastTheta;
}

public void setItems(List<String> items) {
    this.itemNames = items;
}

public int getPX() {
    return getMeasuredWidth() / 2;
}

public int getPY() {
    return getMeasuredHeight() / 2;
}

public float getRadius() {
    return ((float) Math.min(getPX(), getPY())) * 0.8f;
}

protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    float tempAngle = 0;
    float sweepAngle = 360 /6;
    if (this.itemNames != null) {
        int i;
        float offSet = 0;
        this.px = getMeasuredWidth() / 2;
        this.py = getMeasuredHeight() / 2;
        if (!this.textSet) {
            this.textPaint.setTextSize((float) (getMeasuredWidth() / 25));
            this.titlePaint.setTextSize((float) (getMeasuredWidth() / 15));
            this.textSet = true;
        }
        this.radius = ((float) Math.min(this.px, this.py)) * 0.8f;
        float incr = 360.0f / ((float) this.itemNames.size());
        RectF myCircleBox = new RectF(((float) this.px) - this.radius, ((float) this.py) - this.radius, ((float) this.px) + this.radius, ((float) this.py) + this.radius);
        RectF rectF = new RectF(((float) this.px) - (this.radius / 5.0f), ((float) this.py) - (this.radius * 1.1f), ((float) this.px) + (this.radius / 5.0f), ((float) this.py) - (this.radius * 0.6f));
        rectF = new RectF((((float) this.px) - (this.radius / 5.0f)) + 5.0f, (((float) this.py) - (this.radius * 1.1f)) + 2.0f, (((float) this.px) + (this.radius / 5.0f)) - 5.0f, (((float) this.py) - (this.radius * 0.6f)) - 12.0f);

            Log.e("@@rotationOffset", String.valueOf(rotationOffset));
        double actualRotation = this.rotationOffset + ((double) ((incr / 2.0f) + 90.0f));
        canvas.save();
        canvas.rotate((float) this.rotationOffset, (float) this.px, (float) this.py);
        for (i = 0; i < this.itemNames.size(); i++) {
            Paint itemPaint;
            switch (i) {
                case MyDBAdapter.KEY_ID_COLUMN /*0*/:
                    itemPaint = this.item1Paint;
                    break;
                case MyDBAdapter.NAME_COLUMN /*1*/:
                    itemPaint = this.item2Paint;
                    break;
                case MyDBAdapter.NAME_REF /*2*/:
                    itemPaint = this.item3Paint;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    itemPaint = this.item4Paint;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    itemPaint = this.item5Paint;
                    break;
                case 5:
                    itemPaint = this.item6Paint;
                    break;
                case 6:
                    itemPaint = this.item7Paint;
                    break;
                case 7:
                    itemPaint = this.item8Paint;
                    break;
                case 8:
                    itemPaint = this.item9Paint;
                    break;
                case 9:
                    itemPaint = this.item10Paint;
                    break;
                case 10:
                    itemPaint = this.item11Paint;
                    break;
                case 11:
                    itemPaint = this.item12Paint;
                    break;
                case 12:
                    itemPaint = this.item13Paint;
                    break;
                case 13:
                    itemPaint = this.item14Paint;
                    break;
                case 14:
                    itemPaint = this.item15Paint;
                    break;
                default:
                    itemPaint = this.item1Paint;
                    break;
            }
            offSet = ((float) i) * (-incr);
            canvas.save();
            canvas.rotate(offSet, (float) this.px, (float) this.py);
            canvas.drawArc(myCircleBox, (-incr) / 2.0f, incr, true, itemPaint);
            this.item = ((String) this.itemNames.get(i)).toString();
            this.itemLength = (float) ((int) this.textPaint.measureText(this.item));
            if (((double) this.itemLength) > ((double) this.radius) * 0.8d) {
                this.item = this.item.substring(0, (int) (((double) this.item.length()) * ((((double) this.radius) * 0.8d) / ((double) ((int) this.textPaint.measureText(this.item))))));
                this.itemLength = (float) ((int) this.textPaint.measureText(this.item));
            }
         //   canvas.drawText(this.item, (((float) this.px) + (this.radius / 2.0f)) - (this.itemLength / 2.0f), (float) (this.py + ((int) (((double) this.textPaint.measureText("yY")) / 2.5d))), this.textPaint);

 Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.ic_laun);

            //drawImage(canvas, tempAngle,icon );


            tempAngle += sweepAngle;


            canvas.restore();
        }
        for (i = 0; i < this.itemNames.size(); i++) {
            offSet = ((float) i) * incr;

            canvas.save();
            canvas.rotate(offSet, (float) this.px, (float) this.py);
            canvas.save();
            canvas.rotate(incr / 2.0f, (float) this.px, (float) this.py);
            canvas.drawLine(((float) this.px) + this.radius, (float) this.py, (float) this.px, (float) this.py, this.markerPaint);
            Bitmap icon = 
 BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.ic_laun);
            drawImage(canvas, tempAngle,icon );
            canvas.restore();
            canvas.restore();
        }
        canvas.restore();
        canvas.drawCircle((float) this.px, (float) this.py, this.radius, this.circlePaint);
        canvas.drawCircle((float) this.px, (float) this.py, this.radius + (this.circlePaint.getStrokeWidth() * 0.5f), this.rimPaint);
        canvas.drawCircle((float) this.px, (float) this.py, 2.0f, this.rimPaint);
        canvas.drawCircle((float) this.px, (float) this.py, 1.0f, this.rimPaint);
        canvas.drawArc(rectF, 250.0f, 40.0f, true, this.textPaint);
        canvas.drawArc(rectF, 250.0f, 40.0f, true, this.pointerPaint);
        if (actualRotation < 0.0d) {
            actualRotation += 360.0d;
        } else if (actualRotation > 360.0d) {
            actualRotation -= 360.0d;
        }
        if (!(this.selected == -1 || this.selected == ((int) (actualRotation / ((double) incr))) || !Prefs.getMusic(getContext()) || this.resourcePlayer == null)) {
            if (this.resourcePlayer.isPlaying()) {
                this.resourcePlayer.seekTo(0);
            } else {
                this.resourcePlayer.start();
            }
        }
        this.selected = (int) (actualRotation / ((double) incr));
        if (this.lifted) {
            this.winner = ((String) this.itemNames.get(this.selected)).toString();
        }


        canvas.drawText(this.winner, (float) (this.px - (((int) this.titlePaint.measureText(this.winner)) / 2)), (((float) this.py) + this.radius) + ((float) (getMeasuredWidth() / 10)), this.titlePaint);



        canvas.drawText(this.listName, (float) (this.px - (((int) this.titlePaint.measureText(this.listName)) / 2)), (((float) this.py) - this.radius) - ((float) (getMeasuredWidth() / 18)), this.titlePaint);
        if (this.lifted) {
            long currentTimeMillis;
            if (this.lastTheta > 0.0d) {
                currentTimeMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();
                this.currTime = currentTimeMillis;
                this.timeDiff = currentTimeMillis - this.oldTime;
                this.oldTime = this.currTime;
                setRotation(getRotationNumber() + this.lastTheta);
                this.lastTheta -= (double) (0.002f * ((float) this.timeDiff));
                if (this.lastTheta <= 0.0d) {
                    this.lifted = false;
                    Log.e("@finalDone","finalDone"+getRotationNumber());
                    Log.e("@offset","finalDone"+offSet);
                    Intent intent=new Intent(mContext, HomeActivity.class);
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    mContext.startActivity(intent);
                }
            } else {
                currentTimeMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();
                this.currTime = currentTimeMillis;
                this.timeDiff = currentTimeMillis - this.oldTime;
                this.oldTime = this.currTime;
                setRotation(getRotationNumber() + this.lastTheta);
                this.lastTheta += (double) (0.002f * ((float) this.timeDiff));
                if (this.lastTheta >= 0.0d) {
                    this.lifted = false;
                    Log.e("@finalDone","finalDone"+getRotationNumber());
                    Intent intent=new Intent(mContext, HomeActivity.class);
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    mContext.startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
            invalidate();
        }
    }
}

private void drawImage(Canvas canvas, float tempAngle, Bitmap bitmap) {
    //get every arc img width and angle
    int mWheelItemssize=6;
    int imgWidth = (int)radius / 6;
    float angle = (float) ((tempAngle + 360 / mWheelItemssize / 2) * Math.PI / 180);
    //calculate x and y
    int x = (int) (center + (int)radius / 2 / 2 * Math.cos(angle));
    int y = (int) (center + (int) radius / 2 / 2 * Math.sin(angle));


    Rect rect = new Rect(x - imgWidth /2, y - imgWidth / 2, x + imgWidth / 2, y + imgWidth / 2);


    Bitmap rotatedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), null, true);


    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, null, rect, null);

}

private void drawImage1(Canvas canvas, float tmpAngle, Bitmap bitmap) {
    int imgWidth = (int) (radius / itemNames.size());

    float angle = (float) ((tmpAngle + 360 / itemNames.size() / 2) * Math.PI / 180);

    int x = (int) (center + radius / 2 / 2 * Math.cos(angle));
    int y = (int) (center + radius / 2 / 2 * Math.sin(angle));

    Rect rect = new Rect(x - imgWidth/2, y - imgWidth/2, x + imgWidth/2, y + imgWidth/2);


    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, null, rect, null);
}

void OnDestroy() {
    if (this.resourcePlayer != null) {
        this.resourcePlayer.release();
    }
}

public void autoSpin(float seed) {
    if (seed >= 20.0f) {
        seed = 15.0f;
    }

    seed = 8.0f;
    this.oldTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    this.currTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Log.e("@@oldTime", String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()));
    Log.e("@@Random", String.valueOf((new Random().nextFloat())));

    Log.e("@@Random", String.valueOf((new Random().nextFloat())));


    int randomno=3;
    this.lastTheta = (double) ((randomno * seed));
    Log.e("@@lastTheta", String.valueOf(lastTheta));
    this.lifted = true;
    invalidate();
}

}
```

HomeActivity

```
 @Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.autoSpinButton:

          // wheelView.rotateWheelTo(wheelView,3);
            autoSpinButton.setEnabled(false);
            Log.e("@@@Seed", String.valueOf(20.0f * (320.0f / width)));

            wheelView.autoSpin(5.0);

            break;
    }
}
```

main Layout

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<com.spin.wheel.widgets.WheelView
    android:id="@+id/wheelView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/backrepeat"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/autoSpinButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:text="SPIN" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Please Help

Comment: `"I want to rotate the wheel according to fix color on fix point"`, what exactly? what does it mean?

Comment: Sorry, I make the Wheel with 6 item. I want After completion of rotation the wheel stop on a specific item or fix item.

Comment: @pskink right now the wheel stops on random item